# Pending suggested edit message bug

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I just tried to edit a post on Stack Overflow but when I pressed the 'edit' button it showed me this message on a white page.

> [image]

I know what the message means but I don't think it is supposed to show up in a white page. So, is this a bug or is it something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird, you *should have* seen disabled edit link with proper tooltip:

> [image]

So probably what happened is:

1. You visited the question page. No edits in queue, all is good and edit link enabled.
2. Özkan ÖZLÜ suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2248963).
3. You clicked the edit link.

Hard to reproduce properly but this is most likely the case - I agree it's not very user friendly.

The problem is that for users with less than 2K reputation, the "edit" is direct link. No AJAX, so I would suggest to "fix" this by having the live update disable the link if there are edits suggested while you're viewing the page... should be more simple than AJAXifing the link.

Comment: That's the case. That happened with me too many times in the past.

Comment: Or may be he directly typed  `\edit` after Q.no in address bar  . That will not stop loading new page.

Comment: @007 don't think that's the case. He says "when I pressed the 'edit' button" and can't see any reason to lie about it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thnx for the explanation! And 007 no I did not type \edit, I just pressed the button and it happened every time I pressed it.